# Python list: check if all items are the same or not

Tags: python, list

I have a python list of strings and want to check if all list item values are the same or not.

I tried to use condition `if/then` but then I'd need to check all combinations of list values and if list have many items then need to many hard code.

```
if item1 != item1 and item1 != item2 and item1 !=item2 ....... :
    check='wrong'
else:
    check= 'correct'
```

Input:

```
listOfStrings = ['ep:1000' , 'ep:4444', 'ep:1000', 'ep:1000', 'ep:1000', 'ep:1000']
```

**UPDATE**

Example:

```
CORRECT_LIST = ['ep:1000' , 'ep:1000', 'ep:1000', 'ep:1000', 'ep:1000', 'ep:1000']
```

IN correct list all items values are the same, then my list is correct

```
WRONG_LIST = ['ep:1000' , 'ep:4444', 'ep:1000', 'ep:1000', 'ep:1000', 'ep:1000']
```

WRONG_LIST in the wrong list is not all items values string are the some

Comment: "*i want to check if all list items values is the some or not.*", what do you mean with this?

Comment: Can you explain with an example?

Comment: Austin and  Willem Van Onsem i update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compares every element of the list to the first one:

```
listOfStrings = ['ep:1000' , 'ep:4444', 'ep:1000', 'ep:1000', 'ep:1000', 'ep:1000']
check = all(x == listOfStrings[0] for x in listOfStrings)
```

And returns `false` for your test case.

Answer (score 4):

The code snippet you have provided looks a little weird. But if I understand correctly, you are trying to check for the number of unique values in a list.

One way to do it is to convert it to a set and check its length.

```
len(set(listOfStrings))
```

Updated to include working code snippet from @iGian:

```
check = 'wrong' if len(set(list_of_strings)) > 1 else 'correct'
```

Comment: `check = 'wrong' if len(set(list_of_strings)) > 1 else 'correct'`

Answer (score 1):

*IN correct list all items values are the same, then my list is correct*

If you want to check if all items in a list are the same you can check if the lenght of the set of the list is equal to 1:

```
len(set(listOfStrings)) == 1
```

Characteristic for a set is that every element is unique namely to that set.